# From Abu Dhabi airport to center of Dubai via public transport

Tags: public-transport, buses, dubai, uae, abu-dhabi

What is considerably the best option (if any) to travel from Abu Dhabi International Airport to center of Dubai, if public transport is the only option (so: no taxi and no rent-a-car option)?

I know that there are [E100 and E101 buses](https://www.dubaiqa.com/t/where-can-i-find-all-the-routes-and-timetables-for-dubai-buses/110/5) from Dubai Buses service that connects these two cities, but they require me to travel from ADIA all the way to [Samha Village or Abu Dhabi Bus Station](http://dubai-buses.com/InterCity.aspx), which may be a little bit difficult. Do I have any other option?

I'll be travelling with wife and two small girls, if that matters.

Comment: What is best? Cheap? Fast? Less connections? Nice view?

Comment: As per the last sentence ("(...) travelling with (...) two small girls") I'd say that "least connections / direct". As per whole question -- any as it seems that ADIA itself isn't well / at all communicated with Dubai.

Comment: Why is public transport the only option? It sounds to me that you being a group of four, renting a car is something you should seriously consider, both considering cost and convenience.

Comment: @MastaBaba Price! As per my answer below, group of four will travel from Abu Dhabi to Dubai using public transport for AED 116. Corresponding taxi price is AED 280-330 (three times more). One day car rent (checked at europcar) is AED 350 (even more). Convenience, yes. Price -- absolutely not. Does this answer your question?

Comment: It does. I'm surprised about the price. A few years ago, I rented a car in, I think it was, Dubai, drove to Oman and came back for, I think, about 20 USD per day.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that *Al Wahda Sultan Bin Zayed 1st St / Bus Station* equals *Abu Dhabi Central Bus Station* the most convenient way seems to be:

- [A1 bus](https://dot.abudhabi.ae/ckfinder/userfiles/files/service%20A1.pdf) from Abu Dhabi International Airport to *Al Wahda Bus Station* (4 AED, 40-45 minutes),
- [E100 bus](https://www.scribd.com/document/332180213/E100-Al-Ghubaiba-Bus-Station-to-Abu-Dhabi-Bus-Station-Bus-Service-Timetable) or [E101 bus](https://www.scribd.com/document/332180356/E101-Ibn-Battuuta-Metro-Station-to-Abu-Dhabi-Bus-Station-Bus-Service-Timetable) from *Abu Dhabi Central Bus Station* to *Al Ghubaiba Bus Station* in Dubai or to *Ibn Battuta Metro Bus Stop* in Dubai respectively.

Unfortunately, even though I dig quite a lot in the Internet I didn't manage to confirm that *Al Wahda Sultan Bin Zayed 1st St / Bus Station* and *Abu Dhabi Central Bus Station* are indeed two names of the same bus station or if we're talking about two different bus stops here.

Price: AED 4 / pers. (A1 bus in Abu Dhabi) + AED 25 / pers. (E100 bus from Abu Dhabi to Dubai).

Comment: Seems that someone has a problem with this answer, but not enough courage to express, what is wrong with it. Pity.